# Efficient way of slicing large image into 10x10 images (opencv)

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I have a large 2400x1300 png file that I want to slice up into 10x10 pixel *ordered* images and save them into a separate file. I have found multiple methods but I'm not sure which would be the most effective for this large file size. Performance is a key factor.

Here is one of the solutions that looked most promising to me:

```
// source image
IplImage *source = cvLoadImage("2400x1300.png", 1);
int roiSize = 10;
for(int j = 0; j < source->width/roiSize; ++j) {
for(int i = 0; i < source->height/roiSize; ++i) {    
    cvSetImageROI(source, cvRect(i*roiSize, j*roiSize, roiSize, roiSize));

    // cropped image
    IplImage *cropSource = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(source), source->depth, source->nChannels);

    // copy
    cvCopy(source, cropSource, NULL);

    // save 10x10 image as png

    // always reset the ROI
    cvResetImageROI(source);
}
```

}

Comment: instead of createImage+copy just use subimaging. If you wouldn't use the old C api I would show you how. For IplImage and C api you have to find it out yourself ...

Comment: As Micka mentions, since you're using C++, you may as well rewrite this use the C++ API. If you want it fast, you might as write it to be usable with [`cv::parallel_for_`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using C++, let's switch to the C++ OpenCV API to make things simpler (feel free to port this to the old C API if you really need that).

Copy or no copy, the bottleneck here will be in encoding and writing the images to the disk.

The simplest approach that comes to mind is to calculate the bounding rectangle for given tile, and then use [`cv::Mat::operator(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) to get a subregion (ROI) at O(1) cost (no copying). Then just call `cv::imwrite` with an appropriate file name to save it (I'll use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) to generate the filename, although you could use `std::stringstream` as well).

Sample code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void process_tile(cv::Mat const& src
    , cv::Size const& roi_size
    , int32_t tile_col
    , int32_t tile_row)
{
    cv::Rect roi_bounds(tile_col * roi_size.width
        , tile_row * roi_size.height
        , roi_size.width
        , roi_size.height);
    cv::Mat roi(src(roi_bounds));

    std::string file_name(str(boost::format("tiles/tile_%03d_%03d.png") 
        % tile_col % tile_row));

    cv::imwrite(file_name, roi);
}

void save_tiles(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Size const& roi_size)
{
    CV_Assert(src.cols % roi_size.width == 0);
    CV_Assert(src.rows % roi_size.height == 0);

    int32_t const TILE_COLS(src.cols / roi_size.width);
    int32_t const TILE_ROWS(src.rows / roi_size.height);

    for (int32_t r(0); r < TILE_ROWS; ++r) {
        for (int32_t c(0); c < TILE_COLS; ++c) {
            process_tile(src, roi_size, c, r);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::microseconds;

    // Generate some random test image...
    cv::Mat src(1300, 2400, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(src, 0, 256);

    cv::Size const ROI_SIZE(10, 10); // width, height

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    save_tiles(src, ROI_SIZE);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    double t_ms(static_cast<double>(duration) / 1000.0);
    std::cout << "Processed in " << t_ms << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This runs in around 21.4 seconds here, however I see that it's only using ~5% of available CPU. Seems like we could do a lot better by parallelizing this.

But first, let's think a bit about `imwrite`. With 100 pixel images, zlib compression that PNG uses won't really make much difference, and since the files are few hundred bytes (i.e. much smaller than today's file system block sizes), it won't really help with disk usage. That means we can just disable the unnecessary compression to speed things up a little.

```
std::vector<int32_t> compression_params{CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION , 0};
cv::imwrite(file_name, roi, compression_params);
```

This takes 20.7 seconds -- not much of a gain, but still worth it, since we're not losing anything.

Let's have a look at parallelizing this. OpenCV provides a useful tool for this -- [`cv::parallel_for_`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html) which does most of the work for us.

Sample code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void process_tile(cv::Mat const& src
    , cv::Size const& roi_size
    , int32_t tile_col
    , int32_t tile_row)
{
    cv::Rect roi_bounds(tile_col * roi_size.width
        , tile_row * roi_size.height
        , roi_size.width
        , roi_size.height);
    cv::Mat roi(src(roi_bounds));

    std::string file_name(str(boost::format("tiles/tile_%03d_%03d.png") 
        % tile_col % tile_row));

    std::vector<int32_t> compression_params{ CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION , 0};

    cv::imwrite(file_name, roi, compression_params);
}

class ParallelSaveTiles
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    ParallelSaveTiles(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Size const& roi_size)
        : src(src)
        , roi_size(roi_size)
    {
    }

    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& range) const
    {
        int32_t const TILE_COLS(src.cols / roi_size.width);

        for (int32_t r(range.start); r < range.end; ++r) {
            for (int32_t c(0); c < TILE_COLS; ++c) {
                process_tile(src, roi_size, c, r);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    cv::Mat const& src;
    cv::Size const& roi_size;
};



void save_tiles(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Size const& roi_size)
{
    CV_Assert(src.cols % roi_size.width == 0);
    CV_Assert(src.rows % roi_size.height == 0);

    int32_t const TILE_ROWS(src.rows / roi_size.height);

    ParallelSaveTiles parallel_impl(src, roi_size);
    cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, TILE_ROWS), parallel_impl);
}

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::microseconds;

    cv::Mat src(1300, 2400, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(src, 0, 256);

    cv::Size const ROI_SIZE(10, 10); // width, height

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    save_tiles(src, ROI_SIZE);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    double t_ms(static_cast<double>(duration) / 1000.0);
    std::cout << "Processed in " << t_ms << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Now it runs at around 5.3 seconds (on an i7-4930K with 32 GB RAM, writing to SSD on Win10).